# controller constructor parameter in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can we inject a parameter in the constructor of a controller or what is the philosophy of dependency injection in rails ?

Let say I need to inject a payment service into a controller. From .NET world, I would use a DI framework, configure it to inject an instance of CreditPaymentService for IPaymentService dependencies.

In rails, how can we achieve this? Especially for testing and mocking?

I read multiple source stating that we do not need any DI framework to accomplish DI in ruby but I do not figure out how to do it for a controller?

Thanks!

```
// .NET
public class OrderController : Controller
{
    IPaymentService _paymentService;

    public OrderController(IPaymentService paymentService)
    {
        _paymentService = paymentService;
    }

    public object Pay(Order order)
    {       
        _paymentService.process(order.GetTotal());
    }
}

# Rails
class order_controller < ApplicationController

    def initialize(payment_service)
        @payment_service = payment_service
    end 

    def pay
        order = request.parameters(:order)
        @payment_service.process(order)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Give something like this a try:

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController

  def pay
    # you'll need to define payment_params elsewhere in the controller
    PaymentService.call(payment_params)
  end

end
```

`PaymentService` is just a plain old ruby object:

```
class PaymentService

  attr_accessor *%w(
    options
  ).freeze

  class << self 

    def call(options={})
      new(options).call
    end

  end # Class Methods

  #==========================================================================
  # Instance Methods
  #==========================================================================

    def intialize(options={})
      @options = options
    end

    def call 
      # do stuff
      # return something
    end

end
```

I personally like to make `call` a class method, so that I don't have to do:

```
PaymentService.new(payment_params).call
```

Which looks less clean to me. But, that's a matter of pure personal preference.

You can put it in:

```
app
 |- ...
 |- services
 |   |- payment_service.rb
 |- ...
```

Which will cause the service to autoload and you won't have to monkey with `config.autoload_paths`.

Testing the service is trivial (which is the point, isn't it?). Here's an rspec example:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe PaymentService do
  before(:all) do
    @method_name = "call"
  end
  describe "#call" do
    it "responds" do
      expect(described_class.respond_to?(@method_name)).to be_truthy
    end
    context "when using good params" do 
      before(:each){ @params = good_params }
      it "does something" do
        expect(calling_the_service).to do_something
      end
    end
  end
end

def calling_the_service
  described_class.send method_name, params
end

def good_params
  {some: :arguments}
end

def params
  @params 
end

def method_name
  @method_name
end
```

In truth, I do it something a little more like:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # I have a custom module that lets me make this call. Among other things,
  # it creates the call_service method on all controllers. 
  acts_as calling: :services 
end
```

`OrdersController` now knows how to `call_service`:

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController

  def pay
    # Given the acts_as calling: :services call, above, the OrdersController 
    # knows how to inspect the SERVICE_DETAIL constant on PaymentService 
    # and construct the appropriate arguments. In this case, passing in 
    # something like {current_user: 1}
    call_service PaymentService
  end

end
```

I move some stuff into a `ServiceBase`:

```
class ServiceBase 

  attr_accessor *%w(
    options
  ).freeze

  class << self 

    def call(options={})
      new(options).call
    end

  end # Class Methods

  #======================================================================
  # Instance Methods
  #======================================================================

    def intialize(options={})
      @options = options
    end

  private 

    # This method reads the REQUIRED_ARGS AND REQUIRED_VALUES constants 
    # and determines whether a valid service call was made. It also logs
    # errors so that I can go back and see failures.
    def good_to_go?
      # some stuff
    end

    def decorated_options
      @decorated_options ||= OptionsDecorator.new(options)
    end

end
```

And now I declare some metadata on the service in the form of constants. They essentially define the service's interface:

```
class PaymentService < ServiceBase

  SERVICE_DETAILS = [
    {current_user: [:id]}
  ].freeze

  REQUIRED_ARGS = %w(
    current_user
  ).freeze

  REQUIRED_VALUES = %w(
    current_user_id
  ).freeze

  delegate *%w(
    current_user_id
  ), to: :decorated_options

  #======================================================================
  # Instance Methods
  #======================================================================

    def call 
      raise unless good_to_go?
      # do stuff
      # return something
    end

end
```

Answer (score -1):

In Rails, adding a constructor to a controller doesn't make sense. If you're looking to "inject" some functionality into a controller, you could define a mixin module (e.g. under `lib` directory) and `include` it in the controller

```
module Foo
  def say_hello!
    puts "Hello world"
  end
end

class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  include Foo

  def index
    say_hello! # "Hello world"
  end
end
```

or define it as a service class and call it directly

```
class FooService
  def initialize
    puts "Hello world"
  end
end

class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    FooService.new # "Hello world"
  end
end
```

Keep in mind that files under `lib` do not get autoloaded by Rails by default and you'd need to do something like

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

in `application.rb`